# Node Express MySQL multiple routing

Tags: mysql, express, routes

I want to make an route with multiple parameters using Node Express MySQL. Is it possible to do this with traditional url parameters like: `page?id=2&user=10`

Here is a simple query, but the only way of doing it so far is like this: `page/2/10`

```js
app.get("/get-page/:id/:user", function (req, res) {
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id= '${req.params.id}' AND userid= '${req.params.user}'`;";
    let query = db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(results);
    });
});
```

This is just an example.

The reason I would like the traditional way is because, with the "slash" method the parameters always have to come in the correct order, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use the `query` property of the request to access the query string, as in `req.query.id`:

```
app.get("/get-page", function (req, res) {
    console.log('ID: ' + req.query.id)
});
```